# How to find specific entity in a table with auto increment key? (Entity framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, entity

I have following test method:

```
  [Test]
        public void GetUserTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            User user = new User();
            user.Name = "someName";
            user.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;
            _dataContext.Users.Add(user);
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();

            //Execute

            user = _dbService.GetUser(???);

            //Assert

            Assert.NotNull(user);
        }
```

ID is auto generated for User object, so how should I get this particular one? Behind GetUser() im using a Find(id) method from DbSet class.

Comment: I've defined globaly `DataContext` in a test class and injecting this into new instance of dbService in every test method. Is that right?

EDIT: It looks like following: http://pastebin.com/4ak8YTUs

Comment: Yes, I did. It works great. You've explained these issues very clear. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Ok, so I will fix that. Thanks. :) Is there any way to mark you as valuable user in comment section? I'm new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When EF inserts a record that has a database-generated Id, it will read the new Id value into the saved entity. So you can simply do:

```
 user = _dbService.GetUser(user.Id);
```

But I have some comments to make on the testing method itself.

1. Presently, you create a user in the `_dataContext` instance, which is also used in the `dbService` instance. You have to make sure that these instatnces are new *for each test*. If they're not, tests will influence other tests and the test results will become unpredictable.
2. Also, for the Arrange/Act/Assert sections of your test, you should use new instances of the service/context. In your current test, you create a user and in the Act (execute) section you retrieve this same user from the context (because it uses `Find`). In reality, you'll create a service and context) and fetch the user from the database, because `Find` won't find it in the context's cache.